# How to hide everything except textarea while printing using special css

Tags: css

I am new to HTML, CSS and Javascript. I am learning things. WHile learning, I came to a problem how to print only a textarea from HTMl while printing using CSS only.

Comment: Your question probably got down-voted because you didn't supply an example. [Here's a guide on how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

```
@media print {
  * { /* the asterix denotes every element */
      /* belt and braces */
      display:none;
      visibility:hidden;
      height:0;
      overflow:hidden;
     }

   textarea {
      display:block;
      visibility:visible;
      height:inherit;
      overflow:visible;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you but while printing everthing gets hide. Is there anything specific i need to do

Comment: what "textarea" do you want to print? eg <main> then change "textarea" in the css to "main" - that is your selector.